# Performance improvement in an application with next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, performance, next.js

I have an application with `next.js`, I would like to make a code spliting to reduce my bundle and so that the pages are loaded on demand.

However I didn't find a way to do this seeing that I don't care my routes. As an example using `react-router`, where we can use `dynamic imports` on routes.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js handles this out of the box in the build step.

Each route that can exist as an entry point will be built to have a *First Load* version and a delta that will be loaded by the router.

You can try this locally by running `yarn build && yarn start` instead of `yarn dev`.

If you still want to split and dynamically load parts of your JS, you can check out Next's Dynamic Imports https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more things you can do to improve Next.js performance:

1. Select the right rendering mode
2. Defer loading non-critical scripts to load when the page is idle
3. Image Optimization with the Image component
4. Code-splitting client-side code to reduce initial bundle size
5. Server-side rendering with React Server components (Beta)
6. Faster build times with SWC

I have written an article about that here with further details:
https://medium.com/@szaranger/improving-next-js-performance-ad4a05c81888

Comment: The article got deleted could you provide another one?

Comment: @Genie the link has been updated now